# How to stop from alignment with space in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, code-formatting

When I use "Optimize imports" all imports are aligned with spaces like in the screenshot below.

How can I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling this option from 'Preferences/Settings | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript':
[image]